# send Email automatically when new data with specific criteria inserted

Tags: asp.net

I have website in the internet with many data in it. user search in data and filter it. 

user save that filtering criteria. i want send email notification automatically to that user when new data inserted in site that match with saved filtering criteria.

i use asp.net and sql server 2008. i dont have dedicated server. is there any solution for me?

best regards

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the database, you have a choice of multiple things.

**1. Trigger:** If email is configured on your database server, just use an ON INSERT Trigger to send the related information in an email. This will affect the performance of data edits.

**2. Change Data Capture:** Certain RDBMS systems have CDC implemented. You can start a data capture according to your criteria and send matches out as emails.

**3. Query the Database periodically:** Run a query that runs on the hour - every hour, select the inserts that you want and send them via email.

Comment: i use sql server. please explain CDC

Comment: CDC is Change Data Capture. It is available in SQL Server 2008.